# Trying to auto-loging in a website

Tags: vb.net, authentication, web, webbrowser-control

I need to make an autologin job for a friend but I can't finish it, I can't use the id of the textboxes to insert text,

Debugger says: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to resolve it?

[image]

This is the form:

```
Public Class Form1

    'Dim WebBrowser1 As New WebBrowser
    Dim elm
    Public Sub searchbutton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles searchbutton.Click

        'WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_username").SetAttribute("value", "yourusernamehere")
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id_username").InnerText = "yourusernamehere"

    End Sub

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.planetromeo.com/")
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.planetromeo.com/main/login.php")

    End Sub

End Class
```

This is the http:// site.../main/login.php source:

```
<body class="pgLe" id="pgLeLo">
<div id="head"> <h1>Inicio de sesión</h1></div>
<div id="loginWindow">
  <form method="post" action="https://www.planetromeo.com" name="login" target="_top" onsubmit="return submithandler()">
  <input type="hidden" name="PHPSESSID" value="wLzgSbXmdg7Goi1VYDiaXc4Hs4PV71gs" />  <input type="hidden" name="salt" id="id_salt" value="8547695" />
  <input type="hidden" name="resX" id="id_resX" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="resY" id="id_resY" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="secure" id="id_secure" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="initCallSec" id="id_initCallSec" value="0" />

  <div id="loginBox">
    <div class="spacer" style="height:9px;padding:0"></div>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="id_username" size="12" maxlength="70" class="textbox" onchange="document.forms['login'].erinnern.checked=false" /><br />
      <label for="id_username">Nombre del perfil</label>
    </div>
    <div class="inputBox">
      <input type="password" name="passwort" value="" id="id_password" size="12" maxlength="20" class="textbox" onchange="document.forms['login'].secure.value=''" /><br />
      <label for="id_password">Contraseña</label>
    </div>
    <div id="statusBox">
      <select name="status" id="status" class="textbox">
                <option value="-1">Como última vez</option>
        <option value="2">Charlar</option><option value="6">Amigos</option><option value="1">Nada</option><option value="3">Relación</option><option value="4">Cita</option><option value="7">Sexo</option><option value="8">Ocupado</option><option value="0">Ausente</option><option value="5">Invisible&nbsp;(Plus)</option>      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="checkerBox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="erinnern" value="1" id="id_erinnern" class="checkbox" /><label for="id_erinnern"><a href="../service/kontakthilfe/keyword_suche.php?helpid=166" onclick="return openUrl(this.href)">Recordar</a></label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkerBox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="jugendfrei" value="1" id="jugendfrei" class="checkbox" /><label for="jugendfrei"><a href="../service/kontakthilfe/keyword_suche.php?helpid=167" onclick="return openUrl(this.href)">Sin XXX</a></label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="button" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="infoBox">
    <a href="https://www.planetromeo.com//00000000000000000000000000000000/service/login/" target="mitte">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</a><br />
          <a href="https://www.planetromeo.com" target="_top">Activar SSL</a>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And this is the http:// site...com source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=404386888" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" /><title>PlanetRomeo</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function switchLanguage(lang) {
  var frm = frames['oben'].document.forms['jump'];
  frm.lang.value = lang;
  frm.submit();
  return false;
}

</script>

  <meta name="keywords" content="planetromeo,romeo,community,chat,men,kontakte" />
  <meta name="description" content="Online community and dating service for men. Free registration and search." />
      <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/v1/img/touch-icon.png" />
</head>



<frameset cols="*,796,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="links" src="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/left.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
<frameset rows="58,*" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
<frame name="oben" src="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/top.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
<frameset cols="116,680" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="0">
  <frame name="persoenliches" src="/main/login.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />
  <frame name="mitte" src="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/index.php" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="noresize" />
</frameset>
</frameset>
  <frame name="heartbeat" src="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/right.php" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize" />

  <noframes>
  <h1></h1>
  <p>Online community and dating service for men. Free registration and search.</p>
  <p>Sorry, frame support needed!</p>
  <a href="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/top.php">Menu</a><br />
  <a href="/00000000000000000000000000000000/main/index.php">Main Page</a>
  </noframes>

</frameset>


</html>
```

Comment: Loading the frame directly does not work. Load the homepage first, then the frame, im afraid i dont use webbrowsers or sites with frames very often, so i dont know the reason for this

Comment: Thankyou for comment, but can you tell me what you mean with "load the frame"? the frame isn't loaded when I load the homepage? then how I can load a frame please?

Comment: in your posted code, in form1.load you navigate to http://www.planetromeo.com/main/login.php, this is the frame in the sidebar. If you try and open that url in a browser, it is blank UNLESS you have visited the homepage 1st. Clear cookies, or open a private browsing tab, and try it yourself

Comment: So to fix it in your app, you could navigate to the homepage 1st, wait for it to load, then navigate to the frame. Alternately you could load fiddler2 and just replicate the process with webrequests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article suggest a different syntax...

http://vbcity.com/blogs/jatkinson/archive/2009/12/12/programmatically-entering-and-data-using-the-webbrowser-control.aspx

e.g.

Dim usernameTextBox As HtmlElement = Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.All.Item("Email")
usernameTextBox.InnerText = "james.t.atkinson"

but for the button

Me.mainWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("signIn").InvokeMember("click")

Comment: Thankyou so much but i receive the same error using your example:         Dim usernameTextBox As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.All.Item("id_username") 
        usernameTextBox.InnerText = "test"      "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Hmm, I agree with userXXXX now it seems to be something to do with Frames.